# what is the bug in this android layout xml chunk

Tags: android, eclipse, imagebutton, android-linearlayout, runtimeexception

When I try to debug my app I get  a runtimeexception when I include this xml in my layout.  I cannot see what is wrong with it, can you?
I am using android eclipse plugin, eclipse 3.5.2, with the latest android plugin and the latest  java 6...21  on winxppro 32 bit sp3
Thank you.

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/map_button"
  android:src="@drawable/bot_map"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  />

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/filter_button"
  android:src="@drawable/bot_filter"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  />

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/sort_button"
  android:src="@drawable/bot_sort"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  />

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/prev_button"
  android:src="@drawable/bot_arrow_prev"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  />


<ImageButton android:id="@+id/next_button"
  android:src="@drawable/bot_arrow_next"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  />
```

I also get these exceptions at the same time:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3865)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3799)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3770)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem.checkNull(TreeItem.java:205)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem.(TreeItem.java:195)
 at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractTreeEditPart.addChildVisual(AbstractTreeEditPart.java:75)
 at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:210)
 at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refreshChildren(AbstractEditPart.java:771)
 at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:718)
 at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:252)
 at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:211)
 at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.RootTreeEditPart.setContents(RootTreeEditPart.java:140)
 at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:617)
 at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:626)
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle1.UiContentOutlinePage.reloadModel(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.xmlModelChanged(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor$XmlModelStateListener.modelChanged(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.AbstractStructuredModel.fireModelChanged(AbstractStructuredModel.java:553)
 at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.AbstractStructuredModel.internalModelChanged(AbstractStructuredModel.java:887)
 at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.AbstractStructuredModel.changedModel(AbstractStructuredModel.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.DOMModelImpl.changedModel(DOMModelImpl.java:167)
 at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.undo.StructuredTextUndoManager.undo(StructuredTextUndoManager.java:648)
 at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextViewerUndoManager.undo(StructuredTextViewerUndoManager.java:183)
 at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.doOperation(TextViewer.java:3938)
 at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.doOperation(SourceViewer.java:921)
 at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.doOperation(ProjectionViewer.java:1533)
 at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StructuredTextViewer.doOperation(StructuredTextViewer.java:604)
 at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.TextOperationAction$1.run(TextOperationAction.java:131)
 at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.TextOperationAction.run(TextOperationAction.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
 at org.eclipse.ui.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:185)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerWrapper.execute(LegacyHandlerWrapper.java:109)
 at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
 at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.executeCommand(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:470)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.press(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:824)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.processKeyEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:880)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.filterKeySequenceBindings(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:569)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.access$3(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:510)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:125)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1208)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1002)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1027)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1012)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1040)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1036)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1368)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4053)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:346)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:3946)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:342)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4619)
 at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
 at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2411)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3501)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)

Comment: Can we see the enclosing layout for that code snippet?

Comment: If that's your entire XML file then you're missing a root element - layout that contains all those buttons. If that's not the whole thing - please post your XML entirely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your time but the problem just up n went away after I updated my java to 6...22 and restarted everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple root level nodes in XML